# D3.js axis ticks/labels jump after transition in firefox on external monitor

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg

See the following plots:
http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3098488

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8

When I view plot in firefox, the axis ticks/labels jump at the end of the transition when the rescale button is hit.  No such problem in Safari.

Working on a plot and having the same issue.  Why is this happening?  Any workarounds to prevent this?

I am on Firefox 44 on a mac.

**Update:**

See linked gifs for what I am seeing when the axes update:
http://recordit.co/5BEev9II3K

http://recordit.co/I46JhT4Awc

**Second Update:**  Oddly enough, this is only happening when I view the plot on my external monitor, not when I have the window on my Macbook's primary display.

Comment: I see no jump when the rescale animation ends if that's what I'm supposed to look for. I'm running Firefox 44 on a Mac.

Comment: Have added some gifs to show exactly what I am seeing.  Problem should be apparent if you stare at axis labels on animated axis.  I am also on firefox 44 on mac.  Odd that you are not having problem...

Comment: Oddly enough, I just found out it is only happening when I am a) using firefox AND b) viewing on my external display.